# Does strictly increasing functions $f_1$, $ f_2$ ($f_1(0)=f_2(0)=0$) exist such that $f_1(x)\leq f(x)\leq f_2(x)$ for an increasing $f$ ($f(0)=0$)?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f:[0, r] \to [0, \infty)$ be continuous, positive definite, and increasing function, i.e., it is continuous and

1) $f(0) = 0$ and $f(x) > 0$ for $x \in (0, r]$;

2) $f(x) \leq f(y)$ whenever $x < y$ for $x, y \in [0, r]$.

Then, I want to show that there exist continuous *strictly increasing* functions $f_1:[0,r] \to [0, \infty]$ and $f_2:[0,r] \to [0, \infty]$ such that

1) $f_1(0)=f_2(0) = 0$

2) $0 < f_1(x) \leq f(x) \leq f_2(x)$ for all $x \in (0, r]$.

I guess that such functions always exist for any function $f$ satisfying the properties, but stuck with the proof.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For $f_2$ you can chose:

$f_2(x)=f(x)+x$

And for $f_1$ pick up:
$$f_1(x) = \frac{1}{x}\int_0^x f(t) dt$$ for $x \neq 0$ and $f_1(0)=0$.

For $x \gt 0$, we have $f_1(x) \lt f(x)$. For the proof, take $x \gt 0$. As $f$ is supposed to be continuous and increasing, according to the intermediate value theorem, it exists $a \in (0,x)$ such that $f(a) = \frac{f(x)}{2} \lt f(x)$. Then
$$\begin{aligned}
f_1(x) &= \frac{1}{x} \left(\int_0^a f(t) \ dt + \int_a^x f(t) \  dt\right)\\
&\le \frac{1}{x}\left(a \frac{f(x)}{2} + (x-a)f(x)\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{x}\left(xf(x)-\frac{a}{2}f(x)\right)\\
&= f(x) - \frac{a}{2x}f(x) \lt f(x)
\end{aligned}$$

From this inequality, it follows that $f_1$ is continuous at $0$ and is strictly increasing as for $x \gt 0$, $f_1^\prime(x) = \frac{f(x) - f_1(x)}{x} \gt 0$.

Comment: The $2f(x)$ seems un-necessary, could just use $f(x)+x$.  Nice example.

Answer (score -2):

f1(x)=f(x)/2 and f2(x)=2f(x).
f1 and f2 are increasing if f is increasing.

Comment: if $f$ is not "strictly" increasing, then neither $f_1$ nor $f_2$ is strictly increasing.  If the "strictly" condition wasn't there, one could simply use $f(x)$ for both $f_1$ and $f_2$.